# Why is my motor not going the distance I tell it to?

Tags: arduino

I've got a stepper motor that I'm using to power a lift on an automated scanner (if you're interested in getting a larger description of it's full functionality I'm happy to oblige).

Anyways, the problem I'm having currently is that when the lift gets to the top of the scanner it pushes a button that triggers the camera to take a picture, and should then lower and repeat the process.

However, the problem is that once the motor triggers the button it seems to lose track of where it was, and instead of going to the preset distance I had constructed for it either stays in place, or lowers a small fraction of the intended distance.

My thoughts on the matter would be that I believe it to either be a problem with my code and the way I'm controlling the button, or a problem of needing to debounce the button so that I'm reading it as a constant value.

The code is as follows:

```
//Global Variables
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int BUTTON_PIN = 4;                                // number of the pushbutton pin
const int CAMERA_SHOOT_PIN = 2;                          // Pin that controls the shoot function

const int MOTOR_DIRECTION_PIN = 8;
const int MOTOR_STEP_PIN = 9;

//Function Prototypes
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//If the red button is press, the camera will take a shot
void checkIfButtonIsPressedAndTakePictureWithCamera();

//Moves platform tray down lead screw down to zero???
void moveDown(int clicks);

//Moves platform tray up lead screw up to "maxDistance"
void moveUp(int clicks);

//Presses the camera's shoot button and takes a picture
void shootCamera();

//Steps the motor one click
void stepMotorOneClick();

//Steps the motor N clicks
void stepMotorNClicks(int n);

//Changes the current motor direction clcokwise
void toggleDirectionClockwise();

//Changes the current motor direction counterclockwise
void toggleDirectionCounterClockwise();


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Called once when the Arduino is powered up or reset button is hit
/*****************************************************************************/
void setup()
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  Serial.begin(9600); //Initializes serial port at baud rate of 9600 bps  
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);  //set that the button is an input
  pinMode(CAMERA_SHOOT_PIN, OUTPUT);  // set the pin that controls the shoot function

  //Setup motor pins
  pinMode(MOTOR_DIRECTION_PIN, OUTPUT);     
  pinMode(MOTOR_STEP_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(MOTOR_DIRECTION_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MOTOR_STEP_PIN, LOW);


  //moveUp(3600);
}

int clicks = 0;
int moveDirection = 1;

//Called over and over again after setup() executes
/*****************************************************************************/
void loop()
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  clicks = clicks + 1;
  if(clicks > 7000)
  {
    moveDirection = -moveDirection;
    clicks = 0;
  }

  switch(moveDirection)
  {
    case 1: moveUp(1); break;
    case -1: moveDown(1); break;
    case 0: break;
    default: break;
  };

  checkIfButtonIsPressedAndTakePictureWithCamera();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Function Implemented
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*****************************************************************************/
void checkIfButtonIsPressedAndTakePictureWithCamera()
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == HIGH) //If the button is pressed, run through the my functions
  {
    //START CRAPPY HACK
    if (moveDirection == 0)
      moveDirection = 1;
    else
    {
      moveDirection = 0;
      shootCamera();
      moveDirection=-1;
    }
    //END CRAPPY HACK 
  }
}

/*****************************************************************************/
void toggleDirectionClockwise()
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
}

/*****************************************************************************/
void toggleDirectionCounterClockwise()
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
}

/*****************************************************************************/
void stepMotorOneClick()
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  digitalWrite(MOTOR_STEP_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(40);          
  digitalWrite(MOTOR_STEP_PIN, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(40);
}

/*****************************************************************************/
void stepMotorNClicks(int n)
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  for(int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    stepMotorOneClick();
}

/*****************************************************************************/
void moveDown(int clicks)
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  //counterclock
  toggleDirectionCounterClockwise();
  stepMotorNClicks(clicks);
}

/*****************************************************************************/
void moveUp(int clicks)
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  //clockwise
  toggleDirectionClockwise();
  stepMotorNClicks(clicks);
}

/*****************************************************************************/
void shootCamera()
/*****************************************************************************/
{ 
  digitalWrite(CAMERA_SHOOT_PIN,HIGH);  //SHOOT
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(CAMERA_SHOOT_PIN,LOW);
  delay(1);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it reaches the top and presses the button, your code takes a picture with the camera (0.5 seconds), then sets the direction to move down - but doesn't actually move down. So in the next loop, the direction is down so it moves one step down, but the button may still be pressed because one step is so small. So it takes another picture (0.5 seconds), etc etc.

It ends up taking several pictures at the top because the switch is held down.

You may want to move the system down some steps after a picture is taken. Or do not take a picture of the direction is down.

```
void checkIfButtonIsPressedAndTakePictureWithCamera()
/*****************************************************************************/
{
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == HIGH) //If the button is pressed, run through the my functions
  {
    //START CRAPPY HACK
    if (moveDirection == 0)
      moveDirection = 1;
    else if(moveDirection != -1) //If it's not moving down already
    {
      moveDirection = 0;
      shootCamera();
      moveDirection=-1;
    }
    //END CRAPPY HACK 
  }
}
```